# Unable to Load View File in Controller - Getting Error 404

Tags: php, model-view-controller, namespaces, custom-error-pages

I am working on a PHP MVC application, and I'm facing an issue where the controller class is unable to load the view file, resulting in an Error 404 page. I have checked the file paths and ensured that the necessary files are present, but the problem persists.

I have a Controller class with a view method that is responsible for loading the view file. Here's the code for the view method:

```
<?php

namespace App\core;

class Controller
{
    protected function view($viewName, $data = [])
    {
        $viewPath = APP_PATH . '/app/views/' . $viewName . '.php';
        if (file_exists($viewPath)) {
            ob_start();
            extract($data);
            require($viewPath);
            return ob_get_clean();
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('View not found');
        }
    }
}
```

I have a PHP controller class named 'Home' that extends a 'Controller' class. The 'Home' class has an 'index' method which echoes a message and renders a view called 'home'. However, when I run the code, it doesn't load the 'home' view and instead displays a 404 page. I have checked the file paths and they seem to be correct. Can anyone help me identify the issue and resolve it?

```
<?php

namespace App\controllers;

use App\core\Controller;

/**
 * Summary of Home
 */
class Home extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Summary of index
     * @return void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Home controller';
        $this->view('home'); // views/home
    }
}
```

In my MainApp class, I have a loadController method that loads the specified controller and calls the corresponding method. If the controller or method is not found, it falls back to loading the Error_404.php view file. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
    <?php

namespace App\core;

/**
 * Summary of MainApp
 */
class MainApp
{

   
    /**
     * Summary of controller
     * @var string
     */
    private $controller = 'Home';
    private $method = 'index';

    /**
     * Summary of splitURL
     * @return array<string>|bool
     */
    private function splitURL()
    {

        $URL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?? 'home';
        // Get the requested URL path
        $requestUri = parse_url($URL, PHP_URL_PATH);
        // Remove leading and trailing slashes
        $requestUri = trim($requestUri, '/');
        // Split the path into segments
        $segments = explode('/', $requestUri);
        // The first segment will be the parameter
        // $url = isset($segments[0]) ? $segments[0] : '';
        // $segments = array_filter($segments);
        return $segments;
    }
    /**
     * Summary of loadController
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function loadController()
    {
        try {
            $URL = $this->splitURL();
            $controllerNamespace = 'App\controllers\\';
            $controllerName = $controllerNamespace . ucfirst($URL[0]);
            $filename = APP_PATH ."app/controllers/" . $controllerName . '.php';
            if (file_exists($filename)) {
                require_once($filename); // Include the controller file
                
                $this->controller = new $controllerName();
                if (isset($URL[1])) {
                    $this->method = $URL[1];
                }
                if (method_exists($this->controller, $this->method)) {
                    ob_start();
                    $output = call_user_func([$this->controller, $this->method]);
                    return $output;
                } else {
                    throw new \Exception('Method not found');
                }
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Controller not found');
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->load404Page();
        }
    }
    private function load404Page()
    {
        http_response_code(404);
        ob_start();
        $filePath = APP_PATH. 'app/views/Error_404.php';
        require($filePath);
        $this->controller = '_404';
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```